# Event management in a complex backbone application

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I have  complex backbone application with many nested views ( marionette layouts and regions )  and I already use marionette eventmanager to coordinate between these views. But half way through the coding I realize that I am in the process of creating too many events and to complicate even further I have few events triggering more than one actions.

How are events being managed by other complex backbone apps out there.. Any guidelines , best practices, etc., to keep in mind when dealing with events before I dig myself into a bigger hole.

Thanks

Comment: I think there is no possible answer for this.

Comment: I think this is an excellent question - and one I'm wrestling with right now - there will be an answer but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which events framework you're using, so without any assumptions, make sure that you're using Marionette's [EventBinder](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.eventbinder) that is available directly in all Marionette views, and optionally the [EventAggregator](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr) for app-level events that cross too many boundaries and for decoupling modules.

I'm not an expert on the subject, so the following is not authoritative in any way:

- If a parent view needs to trigger an action in a subview in the same module, then using method calling directly rather the event mechanism.
- If a subview needs to trigger an action in the parent view, then use the `EventBinder` as follows:

In the parent view:

```
this.bindTo(subview, 'myscope:myevent', this.myevetHandler);
```

In the subview:

```
this.trigger('myscope:myevent');
```

- For cross-module or cross-view event propagation, basically app-wide events, use the [application's](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md) `EventAggregator`:

  ```
  MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

  MyApp.vent.on("foo", function(){
    alert("bar");
  });

  MyApp.vent.trigger("foo"); // => alert box "bar"
  ```
- For reusable modules that shouldn't depend on a specific application object, you can use a custom `EventBinder` or `EventAggregator`.

For a longer discussion, see:

- [When to use the EventBinder](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.eventbinder/wiki/When-to-use-the-eventbinder) wiki page; and
- [References, Routing, And The Event Aggregator: Coordinating Views In Backbone.js](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/) by Derick Bailey.

Comment: first link is dead :-( - and thanks for a clear answer Tony

Comment: @ErichBSchulz There was some refactoring recently. I update the broken links to point to the new location.